# Running Grunt within a Node.js/Express application

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I have a Node.js/Express.js application that is structured the way it comes out-of-the-box using

```
$ express myApp -c less --hogan
```

So, it roughly looks like this:

```
myApp
└─ /bin
└─ /node_modules
└─ /public
└─ /routes
└─ /views
└─ app.js
└─ package.json
```

How it works right now is that there are .hjs (Hogan) files in `/views/` which are obviously never compiled but directly consumed by the rendering engine.

However, in `/public/`, the .less files are being compiled into minified .css files by default. I am not entirely sure which part of the app does it, but it works.

Say i want to grow this application into something bigger, use more .less files and more .js files in `/public/`, then check, concatenate and minify those automatically (with something like Grunt).

Where do i intelligently place Grunt in this whole workflow / application? A `Gruntfile.js` in the root that is then set to `watch` within /public/? A `Gruntfile.js` in `/public/`? Some internal part of express/node.js (the one already doing the less compiling, for instance)? Something else entirely? What is the best practice here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically people put the Gruntfile in the project root but that may not always be the best place depending on how your project(s) are set up. I may be misunderstanding what you said but I wouldn't usually store the less files in public. I would treat public more like a "target" directory where only the transpiled/concatenated/minified files go.

I would either split the UI into its own project or at least into its own "src" or "fed-src"(front-end dev-src) folder that has its own Gruntfile. Gruntfiles can be hard enough to read already, then if you throw all tasks for front-end and backend in the same file it can be really hard to follow.

Once your concerns have been separated you can have each Gruntfile only watch the src folders that it cares about. Sure, you will have to use two grunt watch processes(1 for UI, 1 for server) but it should be easier for everyone to maintain.

Another reason I like the separate project approach is because after the app goes live there are a lot of times where you just need to make a little change to the UI or the server so its nice to only have to deploy what you changed. The flip side is that it could complicate coordinating the deploy if one is dependent on the other but as long as you don't make breaking changes you should be good to go.